# Python Creating a tick in a class

Tags: python, class

So I'm spawning circles at random in Python and I decided I wanted to make each circle it's own object. So I created a class for them.

I wanted each circle to have their own tick function so that each one can do their own thing. (change colors, size, de-spawn etc.) However I'm having a lot of issues getting the tick method to work.
Here is my code:

```
from random import *
from tkinter import *
from time import *

size = 2000
window = Tk()
count = 0

class Shape(object):
    def __init__(self,name, canv, size, col, x0, y0,d,outline):
        self.name = name
        self.canv = canv
        self.size = size
        self.col = col
        self.x0 = x0
        self.y0 = y0
        self.d = d
        self.outline = outline
        self.age=0

    def death(self):
        pass

    def spawn(self):
        self.canv.create_oval(self.x0, self.y0, self.x0 + self.d, self.y0 + self.d, outline=self.outline, fill = self.col)

    def tick(self):
        self.age = self.age +time.time()

    while True:
        tick()

# var canv = A new Canvas Object (The Window Object to be put in, The Canvice width, The canvice Height)
canv = Canvas(window, width=size, height=size)
canv.pack()
d = 0
while True:
    col = choice(['#EAEA00'])
    x0 = randint(0, size)
    y0 = randint(0, size)
    #d = randint(0, size/5)
    d = (d + 0.001)
    count = count+1
    outline = 'white'
    shapes[count] = Shape("shape" + str(count), canv, size, col, x0, y0, d, outline)
    shapes[count].spawn()
    #canv.create_oval(x0, y0, x0 + d, y0 + d, outline='white', fill = col)
    window.update()
```

So basically I get two different errors from this part of the code:

```
    while True:
        tick()
```

Ether it's a `TypeError: tick() missing one required positional argument: 'self'` or if I put self into the parameters I get `self is undefined`.

So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your posted code doesn't contain the call to `tick()`.  Please post it so we can tell what you are actually doing.

Comment: That is the whole code. and the call is right there Line 31. It gets called evey tick from the moment a object of shape class is created on line 45

Comment: My mistake; I overlooked it.  The call to `tick()` isn't inside of any function -- it's at the _class_ level, meaning it isn't tied to any particular _instance_ of the class and therefore does not have a `self`.  But the `tick()` function is an instance method, which does require `self`.

Comment: Ok so then how would I get the class to call the tick function over and over agane? put the while true at the end of __init__() method?

Comment: If you want `tick()` to be called automatically upon initializing, then yes, that would be one way to do it.  Or if you want to specifically control when the loop starts, you could put it in a separate function called `startup()` or something similar.

Comment: Yes. Exactly that.

Comment: Ok ive got the whole thign working (btw putting it in __init__ did not work because  __init__ is defined befor tick()  But now I have another issue. So after runing it the code gets stuck in the infanint loop of tick. I need the Tick loop in the class running at the same time as the main loop that spawns the circles. I ashumed that having it in the class would let them both run But I gues not. Any advice on how to get both running at the same time?

Comment: If you want two parts of your code to run at the same time, you'll have to use threads.  (And calling tick from inside init should have worked.  You must have made some other error.)